# Dell Dimension L866R: won't power up, no LEDs

Tags: troubleshooting, power, dell-dimension

It froze during work, which is not uncommon. I turned off the power to the power strip, waited a minute, then flipped switch back on. Fan motor runs, but no other sign of life. None of the 4 LEDs in back are lit; power button LED is not lit; no evidence of any signal to the monitor. Fuse? Motherboard? Or trash?

I switched to MAC 5 years ago and use it only to run a couple of programs I need now and then, but don't want to buy new for MAC. Dell had to come out to fix it when it was new 10 years ago, but that was torture I'd definitely want to avoid on my nickel.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the PSU. However, with Dell you need to be careful, because older models were often electrically non-standard - it would probably be worth checking compatibility with that specific model before buying.

More information here: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=339053

Answer (score 0):

I would try another PSU (power supply unit), if a no go, its time to retire it.